# Using Export-CLixml with boolean values

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to export a Boolean value to CliXML using this code:

```
[bool]$test = $true | Export-Clixml -Path C:\test.clxml
```

Returns the error : `Cannot convert value "System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject" to Type "System.Boolean".`

I can export strings to CliXML however:

```
[string]$test = 'true' | Export-Clixml -Path C:\test.clxml
```

What is wrong with the boolean example?

Comment: `[bool]$test = $true | ...` -> `[bool]$test = $true; $test | ...`

Comment: Thanks. If someone posts an answer explaining what was wrong/why the fix worked, I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Export-CliXml` does not return any objects.  It takes your input and turns it into a file.

When you assign a pipeline to a variable, you get the results of the last item in the chain (in this case, no return is `$Null` or an empty value)

Working example:

```
$Test = $True
$Test | Export-CliXml -Path 'C:\test.xml'

$Test = 'true'
$Test | Export-CliXml -Path 'C:\test.xml'
```

Additionally, it is unnecessary and bad style to manually define variable types like you're doing.  The interpreter is intelligent enough to know the types of direct assignments like that.  It's better to do it on the other side if you're trying to type-cast.

e.g.

```
$Test = [String]$True
```

---

In your specific use-case, it appears that `Export-CliXml` **is** returning a `[PSCustomObject]` but with your variable assignment as `[Bool]`, it's failing to type-cast it.

Comment: FTR, `[type]$var = ...` enforces a typed variable (e.g. `[int]$i = 1; $i = 'foo'` => error), so it's neither unnecessary nor bad style.